# Cannot pass params into Yii widget

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to refactor my code, and currently have a function in my component->controller to send slack notifications. However I want to extend notifications, so rather than have multiple functions, passing through params, i thought i'd put all notifications into a widget to be called within the controller.

I've compiled everything i need so far into a widget, but whenever i try and run this, i get the error

```
Undefined variable: type
```

Here's my widget being called in my controller when as item is actioned

```
$this->widget('application.components.DMNotifications', array(
                    'type' => 'slack',
                    'slack_content' => 'event_close',
                ));
```

And here's my component widget

```
<?php

class DMNotifications extends CWidget {

public $type = '';
    public $sendPermission = 0;
    //slack vars
    public $slack_content = null;
    public $newCompany = null;
    public $company = null;
    public $fullname = null;
    public $newInstance = null;

    public static $SLACK_REGISTRATION = "registration";
    public static $SLACK_EVENTPUBLISH = "event_publish";
    public static $SLACK_EVENTCLOSE = "event_close";
    public static $SLACK_EVENTCAPACITYTRIP = "event_capacity_trip";
    public static $SLACK_EMAILNOTIFICATIONS = "email_notifications";

    public function init() {
        if ($type === 1){
            $this->slack();
        }
        parent::init();
}

public function run() {
}

    public function slack(){

$sendPermission = ( Options::model()->isSlackWebhookOptDelegateReg() ? 1 : 0 );


$text = "You have a new message on the " . Options::model()->getSiteName();



        $url = Options::getSlackWebhookUrl();
        $json_data = json_encode(array(
                "text" => $text,
                "username" => "XX",
                "icon_url" => "xx.png",
                "channel" => Options::getSlackWebhookChannel()
        ));
        $post_data['payload'] = $json_data;
        if ($sendPermission === 1){
                $output = Yii::app()->curl->post($url, $post_data);
        }
    }

}
```

if i comment out the type error, i get a different error because nothing is being passed by the params. Either i've totally missed a blinding mistake, or what i'm trying to do isn't a widget.

Can anyone help???

Comment: `($type === 1)` should be `($this->type === 1)`

Comment: Ah, such a stupid mistake, if you can put this in as an answer, i'll mark it correct. Cheers mate